# How to pass multiple parameter from javascript function to controller inside a View?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Currently I have a javascript function for a button inside a Razor view where when user clicked it, a popup message will appear.

```
$("#confirmBtn").click(function() {
           alert("user confirmed address: " + address + street + country);
```

Now I want to change the function so that when user clicked on it, it will send the parameter to the controller "SaveAddress" as HttpPost.

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Use a form and submit the values (or if you want to stay on the same page, use ajax to post the values).

Comment: @StephenMuecke How if I use ajax sir? Really appreciate if you could show me an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options either using Form Postback or by using AJAX

--by Using ajax like below

-- View Section

```
<input type="text" id="address" name="address"/>

<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" Value="Submit" 
 onclick="return myFunction()" />
```

-- Script Section

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var address=$('#address').val();

function myFunction(shipId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Content("~/YourControllerName/SaveAddress")',
        cache: false,
        data: ({ add: address}),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != null) {
                alert("Operation Completed")
            }
        },
        error: function () {

        }
    });
    return false;
 }
</script>
```

--Controller

```
    public ActionResult SaveAddress(string add)
    {
        //Write your code here      
        return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Note:- You can create your model class and able to send multiple value's as for 
demo i am just sending single value.

--by Using Form Post like below

--Model Class

```
public class MyClass
{
public string address {get;set;}
public string street {get;set;}
}
```

-- Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SaveAddress()
    {
        //Write your code here      
        return View();
    }
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveAddress(MyClass myclass)
    {
        //Write your code here      
        return RedirectToAction();
    }
```

-- View

```
  @model YourSolutionName.Models.MyClass 

      @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveAddress","Your Controller Name",FormMethod.Post))
        {
           @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.address )<br/>
           @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.street)
   <br/>
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" Value="Submit" />
        }
```

I hope it may help you. Thank You

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try :D

Comment: Your Welcome.Enjoy

Answer (score 2):

Create a dto class:

```
public class AddressDto
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Your controller method:

```
public ActionResult SaveData(AddressDto dto)
{
    // do stuff
    return Json(true);
}
```

Your ajax request:

```
$("#confirmBtn").click(function() {
    // get values and pass them to dto
    var dto = {
        Address: address,
        Street: street,
        Country: country
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: 'MyController/SaveData',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { dto: dto },
        success: function (result) {
            // do stuff
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use ajax form in MVC

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveAddress", "YourController", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "elementwhichholdsthisform", OnSuccess = "OnFilterSuccess" }, new { id = "frmSaveAddress" }))
{
}
```

Also remember to add reference to

> jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js